# How to debug pending/hanging webservices in Flex 4 with Flash Builder 4?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, rpc

Sometimes (too often...) some webservices "hang". I can see the clock cursor in my app and the network monitor of FB2 shows the webservice as "pending". After waiting a long time, the status changes to "OK" and the clock cursor disappears. How can I find out why a webservice takes sometimes minutes while it usually takes not even a second?

My webservices run on my localhost during development using the Zend AMF Server.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem today. Turned out there was DEFLATE configurations in the htaccess file - commenting them out resolved my problem.

Not sure why compression would affect AMF though?

Another thing I noticed was the issue could be resolved by disabling network monitor, which of course would be useless for debugging.

Hope this helps.